# WinDbg frezzing and unfreezing threads in a loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, windbg

I have a multi-threaded process written in C++ running in WinDbg and I want to go through all the threads and freeze/unfreeze it in random order and interval to reproduce some timing related issues. Do you know, if there is any way to do it using .foreach or even using .wds script file?

Comment: we want to see your cod eso far

Comment: Is the order WinDbg will resume them in somehow not "random" enough for you?

Comment: WinDbg is not very good at triggering breakpoints in random intervals. Is it necessary that the threads are frozen or could they also be suspended? Suspending threads by a small specific tool might be much easier than trying that in WinDbg.

Comment: Suspended will also work for me, if there is a freeware tool available to do that. I prefer to use Windbg, so that I can evaluate the exception, if any. If randomness is not possible, then ordered one is also fine to start with.